# Why is my Hazelcast topic publisher hello world is not working?

Tags: c#, hazelcast

I have made a simple Hazelcast topic publisher in C#.

My code is working on Linux, but not on Windows. Can you help me to understand why?

The code only executes to the line "code stops executing here".

```
public static async Task SubscribePublishToTopic(String topicSubscribe, String message)
{
    await using var client = await HazelcastClientFactory.StartNewClientAsync();
        
    Console.WriteLine("client added");

    await using var topic = await client.GetTopicAsync<String>(topicSubscribe);
        
    await topic.PublishAsync(message);
}

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{   
    Console.WriteLine("We are here");
    await SubscribePublishToTopic("Test-Topic", "Hello World");
    Console.WriteLine("Subscriber added to Test-Topic");    
}
```

Comment: `The code only executes to the line "code stops executing here"` where is this `code stops executing` line? Please provide clear details and a minimal reproducible example so we can further help you.

Comment: i do not see any "code stops executing here"-line...

Comment: My bad, it is the we are here line :)

Comment: Try removing `Task` from `Main`, just a guess at first glimpse.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to remove it like this:

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("We are here");
            SubscribePublishToTopic("Test-Topic", "Hello World");
            Console.WriteLine("Subscriber added to Test-Topic");    }
    }
```

Is that what you meant? 
But it didn't solve the problem. I can reach the "Subscriber added to Test-Topic" line now, but still not the "client added" one

Comment: @MichaelChrestiansen then you have multiple issues, what you described above is fixed then. Have you tried actually debugging your code, if not, please do. `await using var client` try removing `await` from your variable declaration and `await using var topic` remove `await` from that as well, it may or may not address your issue.